# RDD is having only first column value : Hbase, PySpark

Tags: python, hadoop, hbase, bigdata, pyspark

We are reading a Hbase table with Pyspark using the following commands.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
host=<Host Name>
port=<Port Number>

keyConv = "org.apache.spark.examples.pythonconverters.ImmutableBytesWritableToStringConverter"
valueConv = "org.apache.spark.examples.pythonconverters.HBaseResultToStringConverter"

cmdata_conf = {"hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort":port, "hbase.zookeeper.quorum": host, "hbase.mapreduce.inputtable": "CMData", "hbase.mapreduce.scan.columns": "info:Tenure info:Age"}

cmdata_rdd = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD("org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormat","org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable","org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result",keyConverter=keyConv,valueConverter=valueConv,conf=cmdata_conf)

output = cmdata_rdd.collect()

output
```

I am getting the result as below. (Key and Age)

```
[(u'123', u'5'), (u'234', u'4'), (u'345', u'3'), (u'456', u'4'), (u'567', u'7'), (u'678', u'7'), (u'789', u'8')]
```

Instead am expecting Key,Tenure and Age. If I have only Tenure column then its returning Key and Tenure. But If add more columns the result always has Key and Age column.

Can anyone help us to solve this one.?

Note : We are new to this tools

Thank you in advance.

Comment: this example might be helpful https://gist.github.com/2353b5da5099e24da111.git
Ping me if you have any more questions

Comment: Hi Anant,Thank you for the response, but when I click that link I can see a blank page only :(

Comment: Sorry you need to git clone it or you could also use https://gist.github.com/anantasty/2353b5da5099e24da111

Comment: I experienced the same problem when I tried to query more than one column from HBase. I believe the use of `valueConv = "org.apache.spark.examples.pythonconverters.HBaseResultToStringConverter" ` is where it went wrong. We are supposed to get a list / iterables as the values from HBase, but somehow only the last entry of those Java iterables get converted to a python string. This should be a bug ticket.

Answer (score 0):

I you're prototyping and don't want to update your cluster, it can be useful to have a look at happybase (https://happybase.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

The following code does the trick to get my small (9Gig) Hbase table 'name_Hbase_Table' from my cluster in under a second.

```
import happybase
connection = happybase.Connection(host ='your.ip.cluster') #don't specify :port
table = connection.table('name_Hbase_Table')
def hbaseAccelerationParser(table): #create UDF to format data
    finalTable=[]
    for key, data in table.scan(): #don't need the key in my case
        line=[]
        for values in data.itervalues():
            line.append(values)
        finalTable.append(line)
    return finalTable
table =table.map(hbaseAccelerationParser) #capture data in desired format
table = sc.parallelize(table ,4) #put in RDD
```

Comment: Does this really work? I am getting an error on 
       table =table.map(hbaseAccelerationParser) #capture data in desired format
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Table' object has no attribute 'map'