# HBase・PySpark table load Error

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, pyspark

I try to read a table from HBase at PySpark.

This is my code.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *    
host = 'localhost'

keyConv = "org.apache.spark.examples.pythonconverters.ImmutableBytesWritableToStringConverter"

valueConv = "org.apache.spark.examples.pythonconverters.HBaseResultToStringConverter"

testdata_conf = {"hbase.zookeeper.quorum": host, "hbase.mapreduce.inputtable": "test", "hbase.mapreduce.scan.columns": "cf:a"}

testdata_rdd = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD("org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormat","org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable","org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result",keyConverter=keyConv,valueConverter=valueConv,conf=testdata_conf)

output = cmdata_rdd.collect()
output
```

but, I get the error.

```
An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.newAPIHadoopRDD.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable
```

I refer to this link [RDD is having only first column value : Hbase, PySpark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31009988/rdd-is-having-only-first-column-value-hbase-pyspark) for table loading.
I do not use Java and Scala ever. So, I can not understand why the error occured.

If anyone have advise, please tell me.
Thank you.

Comment: Did you added the jars in the calling of spark-submit?

Comment: I use pyspark, and pyspark is shell. So, do not use spark-submit command.

Comment: Ok, Did you added the jars in the calling of pySpark?

Comment: Not added the jars. I am beginner, so I do not know what jar files should be added.

Answer (score 0):

Since I just started with (py)Spak I can feel with you. 
You have to add the jars to your pySpark command with the --jars option. 
Here is a example (we are using Cloudera, so please make sure the jar is in a place that you can reach):

```
pyspark --jars /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/jars/spark-examples-1.6.0-cdh5.10.0-hadoop2.6.0-cdh5.10.0.jar,/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/jars/hbase-examples-1.2.0-cdh5.10.0.jar
```

Your exception was a "ClassNotFoundException" so that means that the jar is not on your classpath.

To check whether your additional jars are appended correctly to the classpath look at the info message you see when pySpark starts up. There must be a message like this:

> INFO ui.SparkUI: Started SparkUI at http://xx.xx.xx.xx:4040 
>   Where x is the IP of your cluster.

Open a browser and navigate to this address. 
You will see the cluster status. Click on Enviroment and browse to the very end of the page. You will see your jars followed by "Added by User"

This is my script that worked for me without any problems: 
    from pyspark import SparkContext, HiveContext
    from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext

```
def main():
    # The SparkContext might be initialized by the spark Shell
    sc = SparkContext("local[2]", appName='SparkHBaseWriter')
    # Config to write to a hBaseFile
    conf = {"hbase.zookeeper.qourum": "quickstart.cloudera:2181",\
                "zookeeper.znode.parent": "/hbase",\
                "hbase.mapred.outputtable": "test",\
                "mapreduce.outputformat.class": "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableOutputFormat",\
                "mapreduce.job.output.key.class": "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable",\
                "mapreduce.job.output.value.class": "org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable"}
    keyConv = "org.apache.spark.examples.pythonconverters.StringToImmutableBytesWritableConverter"
    valueConv = "org.apache.spark.examples.pythonconverters.StringListToPutConverter"
    rdd = sc.parallelize((("row1", ["row1", "cf1", "cel1", "value from PySpark"]),))
    rdd.saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(conf=conf,keyConverter=keyConv,valueConverter=valueConv)

    # read data from hBase
    conf = {"hbase.zookeeper.qourum": "sbglboclomd0002.santanderde.dev.corp:2181",\
                "zookeeper.znode.parent": "/hbase",\
                "hbase.mapred.outputtable": "test",\
                "mapreduce.outputformat.class": "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableOutputFormat",\
                "mapreduce.job.output.key.class": "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable",\
                "mapreduce.job.output.value.class": "org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable"}

    host = 'localhost'

    keyConv = "org.apache.spark.examples.pythonconverters.ImmutableBytesWritableToStringConverter"

    valueConv = "org.apache.spark.examples.pythonconverters.HBaseResultToStringConverter"  

    testdata_conf = {
        "hbase.zookeeper.quorum": "quickstart.cloudera:2181", 
        "hbase.mapreduce.inputtable": "test", 
        "hbase.mapreduce.scan.columns": "cf1:cel1"
        }

    testdata_rdd = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(
        "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormat",
        "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable",
        "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result",
        keyConverter=keyConv,
        valueConverter=valueConv,
        conf=testdata_conf)

    output = testdata_rdd.collect()
    print(output[0])
    # Output in console: 
    # >>> testdata_rdd.collect()[0]
    # (u'row1', u'{"qualifier" : "cel1", "timestamp" : "1499151230221", "columnFamily" : "cf1", "row" : "row1", "type" : "Put", "value" : "value from PySpark"}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I know your question is very old, but I hope this gonna help others.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should add all jars of Hbase to spark lib. If you also have this problem. Probably you also need to add this [1.6.0-typesafe-001 jars](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-examples_2.11/1.6.0-typesafe-001).

It seems to look like spark(py) can't transfer HBase's data to Python's data.

So you need to add this jars to your spark lib or path in `spark-defaults.conf`.

look like this:

```
spark.executor.extraClassPath=/home/guszhang/app/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.6/exteral_jars/HABSE_JARS/*
spark.driver.extraClassPath=/home/guszhang/app/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.6/exteral_jars/HABSE_JARS/*
```